# How to change the size of a modal materializecss

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

sorry if the question is very simple but I'm new using materializeCss

As I can increase the height and width of a modal materializecss ??

Comment: Add so code so that we can suggest answers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In order to set the height and width of the MaterializeCSS Modal you need to edit the CSS of

```
.modal { width: 75% !important ; height: 75% !important ; }  /* increase the height and width as you desire */
```

See more explanation as written by pihyper here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34580086/3133641

Comment: If you find a question to be a *duplicate*, flag it. Don't copy the same answer again.

Comment: that doesn't seem to work (anymore?), but the solution below with max-height works like a charm.

Comment: Yep, I guess the OP should change the accepted answer to the one with the "max-height: 100%; overflow: visible"

Answer (score 8):

to remove vertical height only, add this in modal class. just make sure this definition does not get overwrite (avoid using !important and use specificity instead).

```css
.modal { max-height: 100%; overflow: visible}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the accepted offer is not the best. Use the chrome developer tools or just add the specific modal ID. You may have more than one

```
div#modal5 {
width: 50%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
set your modal class to this code.


    .modal-info {
      max-width: 100% !important;
      max-height: 100% !important; 
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
```